# How to print the elements of a linked list?

Tags: python

I'm dong a Node exercise on python today.  I seem to have accomplished a part of it, but it is not a complete success.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo=None, next=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next  = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

def printList(node):
  while node:
    print node,
    node = node.next
  print
```

So that is the original `__init__`, `__str__` and `printList`, which makes something like: `1 2 3`.

I have to transform `1 2 3` into `[1,2,3]`.

I used `append` on a list I created:

```
nodelist = []

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3


def printList(node):
    while node:
        nodelist.append(str(node)), 
        node = node.next
```

But everything I get in my list is within a string, and I don't want that.

If I eliminate the `str` conversion, I only get a memory space when I call the list with `print`.  So how do I get an unstringed list?

Comment: I'd also recommend putting ``nodelist = []`` as the first line of ``printList()`` and then putting ``return nodelist`` as the last line. This makes the function return a value instead of accessing a variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `str()` on the node, you should access it's `cargo`:

```
.
.
.    
while node:
    nodelist.append(node.cargo)
    node = node.next
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def printLinkedList(self):
    node = self.head
    while node != None:
        print(node.getData())
        node = node.getNext()
```

Answer (score -1):

The code with getData did not work for me.  I am able to print out the list values with:

```
    visited_nodes = set()
    current_node = head
    while current_node:
        print (current_node.val)
        current_node = current_node.next
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.