# How can I create a method to show linked list with data and pointer to next node on screen?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have created a class **Node** that creates a node, and class **singlelist** that will create a linked list.

In the class singlelist I have created **append** method to add a new node to the linked list. 
How would I create a method that will print the linked list on screen showing the node's data and where it's pointing to.

here's my linked list code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self , data , next ):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class singlelist:
    head = None
    tail = None

    def append(self , data):
        node = Node(data , None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=self.tail=node
        else:
            self.tail.next=node
        self.tail=node
```

Comment: You almost certainly did not want to make `head` and `tail` class-level variables.

Comment: I agree.  Define an `__init__(self)` method and declare `self.head = None` and `self.tail = None` in there.

Comment: Ok thankyou I got it!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the elements of a linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907038/how-to-print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

create a show method in your class:

```
def show(self):
    cur_node = self.head         #cur_node is your current node
    while cur_node is not None:
        print(cur_node.data , "-> " , end = "" )
        cur_node = cur_node.next
    print(None)
```

Comment: why you have used `end = ""` in the print statement ?

Comment: @secureamd2 That adds an empty string to the end of each output rather than a newline. It just ensures that the output for the entire list is all on a single line rather than each node being printed on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print an object of a class using the `print` function, you can define a method called `__str__(self)` in your class.

For this particular Linked List, I would do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return_str = ""
    iterator = self.head
    while iterator != None:
        return_str += iterator.data + ", "
        iterator = iterator.next
    return return_str
```

Then, you could just print a singleList object like this:

```
myList = singleList()
print(myList)
```